Deriving a compensation trigonometry function
I was looking for a compensation function for both pitch and roll simultaneously. Someone suggested this function. I have tested the function and it works perfectly. However, I have no idea how it was derived or how did we get it. May someone help? Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Edit : Additional information
Basically, I have a load cell and a load hung from it. If the load cell is tilted, then the reading is going to be off. So I attached a gyroscope to find the angle of the tilt and wanted to compensate accordingly. When I was looking for it, I found it in some SE ( I did not ask the question, I just found the answer). I tried it and it worked perfectly. However, I would like to know how it was derived but I can't find the link to ask the answer owner.

Please give more details using the [edit] option below the question. What physical quantity does Raw reading represent? Why is is affected by pitch and roll? What is the intention of compensation? What does it compensate? pitch angle? Any diagram indicating the pitch and roll axes? Please include a link to where you found this equation if available.

@AJN thank you for the reply. Basically, I have a load cell and a load hung from it. If the load cell is tilted, then the reading is going to be off. So I attached a gyroscope to find the angle of the tilt and wanted to compensate accordingly. When I was looking for it, I found it in some SE ( I did not ask the question, I just found the answer). I tried it and it worked perfectly. However, I would like to know how it was derived but I can't find the link to ask the answer owner.

When pitch and roll angles are specified, often there is an additional information which specifies the order of rotation (pitch followed by roll or roll followed by pitch) which is a part of the definition of $\theta_p$ and $\theta_r$. If your load cell angles are small angles (say  < 10deg), then the order does not matter much. What are the angles for which you found the "... tested the function and it works perfectly "?

@AJN actually, I did not pay attention to that detail. I was trying randomly and it seemed to work just fine. I tried angles between -40 and +40 degrees on both the pitch and roll. But to be honest, I was trying with the pairs of equal angles for pitch and roll. Example, -30 and -30 for pitch and roll. So I DIDNT try something totally random such as +25 pitch and -30 roll for example. Average error was less than 2%, which is great!

Let the load cell measurement axis marked in teal and labelled 1 be tilted by $\theta_p$ and $\theta_r$ along the pitch and roll axes@
Let the resultant angle be $\theta_{net}$. Then
$$
a = r \tan\theta_p\\
b = r \tan\theta_r\\
c = r \tan\theta_{net}\\
c^2 = a^2 + b^2\\
\tan^2\theta_{net} = \tan^2\theta_p + \tan^2\theta_r\\
\theta_{net} = \arctan{\sqrt{\tan^2\theta_p + \tan^2\theta_r}}
$$
The load cell can measure only $\cos\theta_{net}$ component of the weight which acts along the vertical axis. So,
$$
\text{measured (raw) reading} = \text{actual load} \times \cos\theta_{net}
$$

Note
@ : the formula in the question is symmetric with respect to $\theta_p$ and $\theta_r$. However, AFAIK the pitch and roll (and yaw) angles are not symmetric / interchangeable. So the symbols $\theta_p$ and $\theta_r$ are defined as shown in the picture and not to be interpreted as the pitch and roll (and yaw) angles.
Make sure that the gyroscope reports the values shown in the figure and not pitch and roll angles (which are not interchangeable).
Note2
For small angles (measured in radians), a simplified formula is
$$
\theta_{net} = \sqrt{\theta^2_p + \theta^2_r}
$$
No need to compute tangent and arc tangent function.

great job! I was confused with a plane gyro!

@AJN thank you very very much !!!!!!!
